# Sencha Extjs 5 cell editing initial value for editor

Tags: extjs, grid, tablecelleditor, extjs5

I want to start editing on grid cell using the cellediting grid plugin using the function:

```
grid.getPlugin('cellplugin').startEditByPosition({row: row , column: col});
```

I want to edit empty (or not) cell but add my prefix before, and let the user add his, or if he wants then clear the cell (so I don't want masking or changing the cell structure).

Is there any way to start editing the cell with initial text inside? (initial text that wasn't there before editing)

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the beforeedit event of the editor:

```
beforeedit: function(editor ,e ,eOpts ){
  e.value = 'initals';
}
```

Thanks anyways :)